# Rewriting css file to controller's action

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I would like to use .htaccess to rewrite http://localhost/css/file.css to http://localhost/css/generate

is it possible to do it?

it seems to not working. All I have is this .htaccess and Zend Controller **css** with action **generate**

if I go directly to localhost/css/generate I have css output but when I type localhost/css/file.css I get **Not Found**

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^/css/file\.css$ /css/generate

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/css/file\.css$ /css/generate [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

the [L] means "last", which stops it running any subsequent rules if a match was found.

Comment: Hi, I have "Message: Invalid controller specified (css)" so it seems that it is not the last one. :(

Comment: Yes, I am using this as link to my css file instead /css/file.css.

Comment: But do you still get CSS output at that URL as you stated in your question?

Comment: Yes. When I type localhost/css/generate I get css output, all I want to do is to rewrite /css/file.css to /css/generate. I think I will use Zend_Controller_Router_Route to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Place this in your top level `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` and restart Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/css/file\.css$ /css/generate
```

Comment: it seems to not working. All I have is this .htaccess and Zend Controller **css** with action **generate**

if I go directly to http://localhost/css/generate I have css output but when I type http://localhost/css/file.css I get **Not Found**

this is my .htaccess

    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    
    RewriteRule ^/css/file\.css$ /css/generate
    
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: @user942701: Don't add your `.htaccess` as a comment. Edit it into your original question.